# Show countable additivity of a certain probability measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the field consisting of the finite and the co-finite sets in an infinite and ${\bf{uncountable}}\;\Omega$, and define a probability measure $P$ on $\mathcal{F}$ by taking $P(A)$ to be $0$ if $A$ is finite or $1$ if $A$ is infinite. Show that $P$ is countably additive probability measure.

What I need to show is that; for $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\mathcal{F}$ which are disjoint, and $\cup_{n}A_n\in\mathcal{F}$, we have $P(\cup_n A_n)=\sum_n P(A_n)$.

Thus, I need to show that

(1) $\cup_{n}A_n$ is finite iff each $A_n$ is a finite

2)$\cup_{n}A_n$ is co-finite iff eaxctly one $A_n$ is co-finite.

I can show (2). And for (1), if $\cup_{n}A_n$ is finite then each $A_n$ has to be finite. But How to show the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mark the question as answered, I do a copypaste from the deleted answer by voldemort:

You actually need to show that the union is at most countable, as if the complement of a set in your space is finite, then the set must be uncountable. –  voldemort

So, what I understand is that; If $A_n$ are finite then they are countable, then the union is countable, and has to be finite; since if it is not, then its complement will be infinite any way (since it is uncountable), and hence, the union will not be in the finite-cofinite field. Is that correct? –  Meemo

Meemo: that's right. –  voldemort